# MVC Link a Dropdown to a class property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to MVC and I am trying to create a view that will have a dropdown to represent a property in a class. E.g:

```
public class Title
{
    public int Id;
    public string Description
}
```

The values in the Title class would be something like:
1 Mr
2 Mrs
3 Miss
[etc]

The class that I want to represent in the view looks like this:

```
public class Contact
{
    public int Id;
    public int Name;
    public Title  Title;
}
```

I have added the dropdown to the form with this code:

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownList("Title", "Please Select")
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)
</div>
```

and populated the dropdown with:

```
ViewBag.Title = new SelectList(db.Titles.ToList(), "Id", "Description");
```

But how do I link the dropdown to the Model on the post? Currently the page complains that "1" is not a valid value (when I choose Mr).

Thanks

Comment: where did you bind dropdownlist with viewbag value? its not there in ur code

Comment: `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Title.ID, (SelectList)ViewBagTitleList. "Please Select")` (note: change the name of the `ViewBag` property (it cant be the same as the model property)